# Netbeans sql auto increment in insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, netbeans

I have created my table and modified my column so it INCREMENT BY 1

I don't understand how to actually use that auto increment in to an INSERT query,

If I try to skip it, thinking the table would automatically pick it up, it throws an error. 
If I try to use a value such as 0, the second time I run the query, it throws an error for repeating primary keys.

How to actually use it in an insert, so it increments on its own every time I run a query?

Comment: Can you show us your create table statement and the statement you used to create the auto increment column?

Comment: When you skip it, what error do you get?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen


`CREATE TABLE "CAMPAIGNS"
(      
   "campaignName" VARCHAR(200),     
   "campaignLocation" VARCHAR(200),
   "campaignManager" VARCHAR(200)
 
);
`
And then I add a custom column with the netbeans IDE, and I put INCREMENT BY 1 in the window

Comment: Also, which database are you actually using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen error is `[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42802] The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns.`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen JavaDB

Comment: I don't know this database.  It sounds like your insert statement is unbalanced.

Comment: The `SQLState` suggests that your database is DB2, however the tag is MySQL. If you're looking for a DB2 Solution, please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13466347/2298301. And, if you're wanting to add an auto-increment to MySQL, then something like... `CREATE TABLE your_table (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY (id) );`