# auto_increment command for SQL is not working

Tags: sql, db2, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user(
  user_id BIGINT not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  user_username VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  user_password VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
  );
```

Ι keep getting an error that says

> "An unexpected token "," was found following "Y KEY AUTO_INCREMENT".
>   Expected tokens may include: "". SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: IBM DB2 Express-C

Comment: user_id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1
   MINVALUE 1
   MAXVALUE 2147483647
   NO CYCLE
   CACHE 20
   NO ORDER ),

Answer (score 0):

you can use IDENTITY(1,1) for that as:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user(
  user_id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) not NULL,
  user_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  user_username VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  user_password VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

or also you can set it using designer.

Comment: ***IF*** you're using Microsoft **SQL Server** - yes - but not for other systems. Since the OP didn't say **what** RDBMS he's using, this is very unsure to be an exact match .....

Comment: I'm still getting an error that says "An unexpected token "IDENTITY" was found following "USER( user_id BIGINT". Expected tokens may include: "DEFAULT". SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? @JoojoDontoh

Comment: @marc_s you are absolutely right

Comment: ibm db2 express-c

Comment: may be this will give you an idea >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466347/how-to-auto-increment-in-db2